# WSO2 ESB MailTransportListener not receiving

Tags: wso2, mailto, wso2-esb

I just installed my brand new WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.  This is the latest version which I downloaded yesterday.

I am trying to get my ESB to receive e-mail from a server.  I have tried POP3 and IMAP.  I have been using several references to help me(Since I am a new member, my reputation does not yet allow me to post proper links to all my references):

- stackoverflow.com/questions/27376833/wso2-mailto-transport-emptied-my-inbox
- javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html
- javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html
- sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.fr/2013/10/how-to-receive-emails-to-wso2-esb.html
- charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-enable-mail-transport-for-wso2.html
- irhamiqbal.wordpress.com/how-to-receive-email-using-wso2-esb/
- jayalalk.blogspot.com/2014/06/wso2-esb-mail-sending-with-html-complex.html

And of course the official documentation:

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/MailTo+Transport
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS501/Using+Mail+transport+to+Invoke+Web+Services

All of my reading leads me to believe that I have everything set up properly (or if not properly, good enough to get some error messages to troubleshoot).

I did restart the WSO2 ESB and the following message shows up in the console log:

```
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2016-08-02 21:45:37,237] INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener} - MAILTO listener started
```

I get no other indication in the logs one way or another.

I edited (and double checked) my $CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml, and I'm pretty sure I have the mail transport enabled properly:

```
<transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
    <!-- configure any optional POP3/IMAP properties
    check com.sun.mail.pop3 and com.sun.mail.imap package documentation for more details-->
</transportReceiver>
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">my.smtp.server</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">my@user.id</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">password</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">my@email.com</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

And, finally, I have my Proxy Service setup (in its current iteration, anyway):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JasperEmailPOP3"
       transports="mailto"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="senderAddress"
                   expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Date" expression="$trp:Date"/>
            <property name="Subject" expression="$trp:Subject"/>
            <property name="Content-Type" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>
            <property name="From" expression="$trp:From"/>
         </log>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">my.pop3.email</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">my@email.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">jasper@eryjus.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">password</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">995</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

With all of this, my question is: is there something else I am missing to get the ESB to at least attempt to retrieve e-mail?  What bothers me is I am not getting any error messages to troubleshoot (such as my mail not being in plain test).

Comment: Were you successful in solving your problem? I want to extract attached files from the incoming mail and put them on my local filesystem. I could not find much samples out there. Have you consider this scenario too?

Comment: Hi, I'm interested too: I can't find samples of reading email attachments. Moreover, the attachments will be signed with a SMIME certificate. I guess once I can retrieve attachments I'll have to deal with certificate through a custom Java mediator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same scenario with a Gmail account and it works fine for me, seems like some mis-configuration in your POP server. You need to add following property as well.

```
<parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

See the full proxy configs below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JasperEmailPOP3"
       transports="mailto"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="senderAddress"
                   expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Date" expression="$trp:Date"/>
            <property name="Subject" expression="$trp:Subject"/>
            <property name="Content-Type" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>
            <property name="From" expression="$trp:From"/>
         </log>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">pop.gmail.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">ycwso2test</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">ycwso2test@gmail.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">wso2qa123</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">995</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Also if you need to further debug this you can enable DEBUG logs. To do this add the following line to repository/conf/log4j.properties and restart.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was able to get the information I need with the DEBUG logs.  Good call on the POP server setup, by the way.  I think my ISP (fatcow.com) has a problem with plain/text over port 995. When I set it back to port 110 and commented out the line `<parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>` it started working.  Now I can work on making it what I really want.

Comment: Hi Adam, just a dumb question: do you need to call the proxy "yourself" (by an URL ?) to retrieve mails or by just deploying this proxy you'll get the mails ?