# How to receive emails using WSO2 MI?

Tags: email, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

This is only on a localhost setup. Followed [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/file-processing/mailto-transport-examples/#receiving-emails) documentation and set the following in my proxy (replacing the email address, username, and password with my personal email):

```
<parameter name="transport.mail.Address">synapse.demo.1@gmail.com</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.host">pop.gmail.com</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.port">995</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.user">synapse.demo.1</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.password">mailpassword1</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
<parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

After starting the proxy service on my localhost, when I send an email to my personal email nothing is picked up. Not sure if I have to do anything else?

Copied and tried the proxy service given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736595/19261326) older answer but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers are below.

First, you need to enable `mailto` transport receiver in `axis2.xml` to receive Emails. See the below.

```xml
    <transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
        <!-- configure any optional POP3/IMAP properties
        check com.sun.mail.pop3 and com.sun.mail.imap package documentation for more details-->
    </transportReceiver>
```

Also, with `Gmail` POP3 servers you can no longer use your email password for authentication. This is because on the 30th of May 2022 `Less Secure` App option was [removed](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) by Google. So instead of using your password, you need to generate an App password. You can refer [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521) to generate an App password. Make sure your account has two-factor authentication enabled, otherwise this option will be disabled. Once the above is done following proxy will work.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Email" startOnLoad="true">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="senderAddress" expression="get-property('transport', 'From')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="Date" expression="$trp:Date"/>
                <property name="Subject" expression="$trp:Subject"/>
                <property name="Content-Type" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>
                <property name="From" expression="$trp:From"/>
            </log>
            <drop/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">pop.gmail.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">user1</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.port">995</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">user1@gmail.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">APP_PASSWORD</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">995</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
</proxy>
```

If you still see issues you can enable debug logs and see what's happening. Add the following line to `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener=DEBUG
```